# Write ini file values without overwriting whole ini with boost

Tags: c++, boost

I have function that writes one section of ini file:

```
boolean saveSSVar()
{
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;


    ptree pt;
    pt.put(SRV_ID, ID);
    pt.put(SRV_LOG_LEVEL, LogLevel);



    write_ini( INI_FILE_NAME, pt );

    return true;
}
```

Problem is that it overwrites whole file instead one section. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just

1. read in original INI
2. update values in `ptree`
3. write resultant tree to INI

Note that not all information will roundtrip 100% (see [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.ini_parser) for limitations)

See also: [c++ boost library - writing to ini file without overwriting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067475/c-boost-library-writing-to-ini-file-without-overwriting/27069259?s=10|1.0833#27069259)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to keep ptree as global or static.